# Completely confused about this simple regex in preg_match

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

I'm trying to validate some input, but I'm getting reverse results (or maybe I have completely missed the use of the `preg_match` function?)

This is my code:

```
$check_firstname = "@#";
if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/', $check_firstname)) echo "valid"; else echo "invalid";
```

I would have thought that this regex in `preg_match` would not only allow alphanumeric characters, but this input gives an output of `valid`! If the input (in this case, `check_firstname`) is NOT alphanumeric, why is `preg_match` finding a match? I've already checked the documentation but I don't understand what's happening.

My real requirement is to allow the dash character (-) along with alphanumeric characters in the user input, but I don't see how to get anywhere when my basic test seems not to be working.

### Edit

Thank you for your responses! I get the problem with the caret now. However I forgot mention that apart from dashes, I need to allow spaces as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply put the caret (`^`) in the wrong position :)

`[^...]` matches any character *not* found between the square brackets.

`^` alone means the beginning of the string.

`[^A-Za-z0-9_]` means that the regex will check for the first character in the string and if that character is not an alphanumeric, or underscore, it will pass.

To allow only alphanumeric characters and a dash, you will use:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$
```

The `+` (one or more times) and `$` (end of string) operators will ensure that the whole string is checked.

Note that this regex doesn't allow underscores (`_`). If you need to allow them, you can use the regex in Casimir's answer.

To allow spaces as well:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\s-]+$
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I need to allow spaces as well? I've just edited my question, I forgot to mention that it in, I don't need underscores but I need spaces and dashes allowed.

Comment: To allow for spaces, you can simply include an `\s` inside the character class: `^[A-Za-z0-9\s-]+$` I will put it in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the `^` symbol which means "not" when it's inside of brackets. Here's a [good site on syntax for Regex.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) In single line mode, the `\s` allows for tabs and spaces. *Note:* the hyphen needs to go last so it doesn't try and treat it like a range.

```
if(preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9\s-]+$/i', $check_firstname)){
echo "valid"; } else {echo "invalid";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/', $check_firstname)===1){ echo 'Valid'; } else { echo 'Invalid'; }
```

Just incorrect place to put the ^ character, and also added the $ symbol to indicate the end of the match.

You should also be using a type/value comparison as this function can return 3 different values:

```
(int)1 = Match found
(int)0 = Match not found
(bool)false = Error
```

Comment: `/^[...]$/` matches exactly one character, that's propably not what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
if(preg_match('/^[\w- ]+$/', $check_firstname)) echo "valid"; else echo "invalid";
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. However I do need spaces too (just edited the question - sorry forgot about that requirement).

Answer (score 0):

Why not stick with your regex and change the interpretation?

```
if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/', $check_firstname)) echo "invalid"; else echo "valid";
```

If the regex matches, you know that $check_firstname contains at least one char that is not a letter, a number or underscore  --> that makes it invalid

qed